# Function to use multiple types of structures

Tags: c++, templates

I a function prototype:

`void writeToFile(ofstream&, vector<SoftwareDeveloper>, vector<Manager>, vector<Tester>, vector<TeamLeader>);`

and the function body:

```
void writeToFile(ofstream& fileToBeWrittenTo, vector<SoftwareDeveloper> firstArray, vector<Manager> secondArray, vector<Tester> thirdArray, vector<TeamLeader> fourthArray)
{
for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.size(); i++)
{
    fileToBeWrittenTo << firstArray[i].identificationCode << "|" << firstArray[i].firstName << "|" << firstArray[i].lastName << "|" << firstArray[i].typeOfEmployee << "|";
    for (int j = 0; j < firstArray[i].knownLanguages.size(); j++)
        fileToBeWrittenTo << firstArray[i].knownLanguages[j] << ':';
    fileToBeWrittenTo << endl;
}

for (int i = 0; i < secondArray.size(); i++)
{
    fileToBeWrittenTo << secondArray[i].identificationCode << "|" << secondArray[i].firstName << "|" << secondArray[i].lastName << "|" << secondArray[i].typeOfEmployee;
    fileToBeWrittenTo << endl;
}

for (int i = 0; i < thirdArray.size(); i++)
{
    fileToBeWrittenTo << thirdArray[i].identificationCode << "|" << thirdArray[i].firstName << "|" << thirdArray[i].lastName << "|" << thirdArray[i].typeOfEmployee << "|" << thirdArray[i].isAutomated;
    fileToBeWrittenTo << endl;
}

for (int i = 0; i < fourthArray.size(); i++)
{
    fileToBeWrittenTo << fourthArray[i].identificationCode << "|" << fourthArray[i].firstName << "|" << fourthArray[i].lastName << "|" << fourthArray[i].typeOfEmployee;
    fileToBeWrittenTo << endl;
}

};
```

Could I be able to use a template to make the function get multiple types of structures, and I mean, to just replace `vector<SoftwareDeveloper>` and so on with and `H` data type just like this?

```
template<typename H>
void writeToFile(ofstream& fileToBeWrittenTo, H firstArray, H secondArray, H thirdArray, H fourthArray)
{
for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.size(); i++)
{
    fileToBeWrittenTo << firstArray[i].identificationCode << "|" << firstArray[i].firstName << "|" << firstArray[i].lastName << "|" << firstArray[i].typeOfEmployee << "|";
    for (int j = 0; j < firstArray[i].knownLanguages.size(); j++)
        fileToBeWrittenTo << firstArray[i].knownLanguages[j] << ':';
    fileToBeWrittenTo << endl;
}

for (int i = 0; i < secondArray.size(); i++)
{
    fileToBeWrittenTo << secondArray[i].identificationCode << "|" << secondArray[i].firstName << "|" << secondArray[i].lastName << "|" << secondArray[i].typeOfEmployee;
    fileToBeWrittenTo << endl;
}

for (int i = 0; i < thirdArray.size(); i++)
{
    fileToBeWrittenTo << thirdArray[i].identificationCode << "|" << thirdArray[i].firstName << "|" << thirdArray[i].lastName << "|" << thirdArray[i].typeOfEmployee << "|" << thirdArray[i].isAutomated;
    fileToBeWrittenTo << endl;
}

for (int i = 0; i < fourthArray.size(); i++)
{
    fileToBeWrittenTo << fourthArray[i].identificationCode << "|" << fourthArray[i].firstName << "|" << fourthArray[i].lastName << "|" << fourthArray[i].typeOfEmployee;
    fileToBeWrittenTo << endl;
}

};
```

Comment: This is as far from OOP as humanly possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the helpful comments: This answer assumes that all of your types have the same data members, although some of the types might also have other attributes that should not be exported, though. Is not that much of an realistic use case but the only one where I could see that a template solution would make real sense here. Of course, if all of the types really are the same, you should not have multiple classes.

The usual approach here would be to let your `SoftwareDeveloper`, `Manager`, ... classes inherit from the same base class and then store them in an array `vector<unique_ptr<Person>>`.

If this does not make sense here, you could indeed use a template:

```
template<typename H>
void writeToFile(ostream& fileToBeWrittenTo, const H& arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        fileToBeWrittenTo << arr[i].identificationCode << "|" << arr[i].firstName << "|" << arr[i].lastName << "|" << arr[i].typeOfEmployee << "|";
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].knownLanguages.size(); j++)
            fileToBeWrittenTo << arr[i].knownLanguages[j] << ':';

        fileToBeWrittenTo << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And now, you can call this template with all of your singular vector instances:

```
writeToFile(stream, softwareDeveloperVector);
writeToFile(stream, managerVector);
// and so on
```

This way, instead of putting everything multiple times into one function, you have a smaller function that you can call multiple times. These multiple calls can be put into another function, of course. In any way, this will save you code (and possibly nerves and time if you want to change something later).

Some other things to notice here:

- you should use ostream instead of ofstream because this is more
  general; you can also use file streams then but also other output
  streams like cout

  you should pass H as reference here, so that it is passed by reference and not by value which is substantially slower because the whole array is copied, which might not even be possible or make sense depending on your Employee type
- this function does hot change your vector, so you should pass the
  vector as const => together with my point before, you should use
  `const H&`
- this is not important but usually one would name your template
  parameter T

Comment: Avoid vectors of naked pointers, use vectors of smart pointers.

Comment: Different types of person actually have different data members, so a template solution isn't going to work that well. If they all had the same members, one should have asked "why are they of different types?"

Comment: You are right, this probably does not make sense. Judging from OPs solution I assumed that most of the types have the same data members. Of course, this does not make sense in itself

Comment: You also probably should mention that formatting of different person types should be handled by a virtual function defined in the base and overridden as needed in the children.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is that instead of using `template<typename H>` we can use `#define H vector<SoftwareDeveloper>` and so on and use it inside the function declaration
`void writeToFile(ofstream& fileToBeWrittenTo, H firstArray, K secondArray, J thirdArray, L fourthArray)`

Comment: "One possible **solution** is" You have misspelled **way to get fired**. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

`vector<SoftwareDeveloper>`, `vector<Manager>`, `vector<Tester>`, `vector<TeamLeader>` are different types, so you need to differentiate them. You can do it like,

```
template<typename H, K, J, L>
void writeToFile(ofstream& fileToBeWrittenTo, H firstArray, K secondArray, J thirdArray, L fourthArray)
{
...
}
```